# Como enviar por medio de Postman dos parámetros (xml y string)

Tags: c#, android-studio, webservice, postman

Buen dia, tengo este problema: Quiero consumir una api que cree, y me recibe dos string.

```
[HttpPost]
public Response RegistrarVenta(string xml, string nombreUsuario)
{
/*Codigo c#*/
}
```

Esta api la consumo desde un proyecto en Android Studio y funciona, entra al método y todo bien. pero al momento de querer hacer una prueba en Postman no puedo enviar el xml por que la cadena es muy larga.

[image: Postman]

Comment: Es que ni configurando el server te va a funcionar.  Un controlador del tipo API recibe los parámetros en el `body` para el método POST ( no en la URL)., tendrías que colocar `[FromQuery]` para que funcionara. Pero NO te lo recomiendo, lo correcto sería que ese XML lo enviaras en el body, y lo mejor es que además de eso, configuraras la serialización para recibir ese XML directamente como objeto C#

Comment: En ese caso cambiando el metodo para que reciba un solo parámetro tipo string, como le enviaria el xml?

Answer (score 0):

Le estas apuntando el endpoint correcto apunta a

```
api/RegistrarVenta
```

o

```
[HttpPost("Ventas")]
```

Tambien escribiste en el parametro **xm** en vez de **xml**

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero es entender que los datos se pueden enviar en muchos lugares, por ejemplo

- En la URL
- En un form
- En el body
- etc

El postman hace referencia a ello en esta parte

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una función de un controlador recibe los datos de manera predeterminada por "form", a menos que arriba en el controlador pongas `[ApiController]` en este caso la manera predeterminada pasa a ser por `Body`

De todas maneras siempre puedes setear los argumentos para indicar el lugar desde donde vienen los datos, ejemplo

```
public void Registrar([FromForm]string xml, [FromQuery] string nombreUsuario)
```

Y cuando los datos vienen el `body`, el sistema (de manera predeterminada) los espera como JSON

---

### Enviando el "xml" en el form y "nombreUsuario" en la URL

La función debería verse así:

```
[HttpPost("Registrar")]
public void Registrar([FromForm]string xml, [FromQuery] string nombreUsuario)
{
            
}
```

Y en el Postman

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

### Enviando todo el body

Recuerda que de manera predeterminada es JSON, y para recibir los datos debemos crear una clase

```
public class Peticion
{
     public string xml { get; set;}
     public string nombreUsuario { get;set;}
}
```

La función del controller

```
[HttpPost("Registrar")]
public void Registrar(Peticion p)
{
            
}
```

El Postman:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

### Enviando el "xml" como XML

También podemos enviar un XML y deserializarlo

En el program.cs debemos colocar:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters();
```

Luego debemos crear una clase equivalente al XML, por ejemplo

```
public class Venta
{ 
    public int IdVenta { get; set; }
    public string Codigo { get; set; }
}
```

La función del controlador

```
[HttpPost("Registrar.{format}"),FormatFilter]
public void Regsitrar(Venta venta, [FromQuery]string nombreUsuario)
{
            
}
```

Esta función será capaz de recibir JSON y XML, ejemplo de url:

- dominio.com/controladorName/Registrar.xml?nombreUsuario=asd
- dominio.com/controladorName/Registrar.json?nombreUsuario=asd

Luego en el postman:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como verás en el XML hay que agregar los namespace, para quitarlos hay que configurar la clase, por ejemplo

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class Venta
{
    [DataMember]
    public int IdVenta { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Codigo { get; set; }
}
```

Y ahora en el postman:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Excelente explicación y si funcionó, pero igual tuve que cambiar el web config por que la cadena que enviaba como tipo Request era muy larga. **` maxQueryStringLength ="2097151" `** .

Comment: Cuanto me alegro !! Entonces marca la respuesta como aceptada...Saludos